# Adsense ads not appear

Tags: javascript, php, html, adsense

I have a website that runs on Apache2 and has code in PHP and JS + HTML.

Link to site: http://goldfaucet.xyz

This is the code of my ad unit:

I have an approved Adsense account that already was showing ads and getting revenue since months.

I created an Adsense ad unit and placed it on that website but it is not appearing.

If it can be useful, my account is not banned neither I use an adblocker.
Also ads work when tested in Adsense sandbox here: http://ctrlq.org/sandbox/

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- 728x90_leaderboard -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

What can be the problem? There are no errors showing in debug console.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `async`  then try:

```
<script class="cc-onconsent-inline-advertising" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

You can also follow this link:
http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-adsense-responsive-design/25252/

Comment: can you test your code in another page? look if it is rendering or not.

Comment: test page on same domain.. http://goldfaucet.xyz/test.html and test page on other domain.. http://goldrotator.com/test.html result is the same

Comment: Try "<script class="cc-onconsent-inline-advertising" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>" instead of "<script defer src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>"

Comment: Check my Updated Answer

Comment: we are near the solution I think.. ads is appearing (even if in the wrong format and with lot of errors in the console)  "Blocked a frame with origin "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://goldfaucet.xyz".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match."

Comment: I found different between adsbygoogle.js and show_ads.js. if i use your code with adsbygoogle.js its rendering ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112603/discussion-between-thestubborndev-and-munaz).

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a account level ban, could be Site level ban, the niche is related to faucet.  Definitely not the allowed niche.

You can use the below tool to test the adsense ads in your site.

ctrlq.org/sandbox/

You have to provide your site URL in the tool, if it shows blank page, then your site might have been banned or no ads to show related to niche of your site.

The answer might be useful for other users.